# Is it safe to re-use structure using variables on PDO?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

i was trying to save time on my project by re utilizing my insert script so i changed

This

```
if ( !empty($_POST)) {

    // keep track post values
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];


    // insert data
    if ($valid) {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name,email,mobile) values(?, ?, ?)";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($name,$email,$mobile));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
```

To this:

```
if (!empty($_POST)){
      function filter($data){
                $data=trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
                return $data;
           }

      foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

     //Create variables with the same name as  the fields and sanitize with filters 
                  $$key = filter($value);

                //1 - Case <checkbox> 
                if(is_array($value)){
                    //Get field value and save in array prepKey 
                    $prepKey[] = filter(implode(",",$value));
                }

                //2 - Case <input>
                 if(!is_array($value)){
                    //Get field value and save in array prepKey     
                    $prepKey[] = filter($value);
                }

              //Get field name and save in array prepField
                    $prepField[] = $key;
                }

   //Transform field array to comma separated string ex: name,email,address
            $field = implode (",", $prepField);

            //Count inputs
            $count_post = count($_POST);

     //Prepare interrogations signs and save on array prepInt for PDO ex:?
            for($i=1;$i<=$count_post;$i++){
                $prepInt[] = "?";
              }
     //Transform interrogations array to comma separated string  ex: ?,?,?
            $int = implode (",", $prepInt);


            // insert data
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO customers ($field) values($int)";
                //SQL become "INSERT INTO customers (name,email,address) values (?,?,?) ";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute($prepKey);
                //prepKey become 'array($name,$email,$address)'
            Database::disconnect();

           header("Location: index.php");

}
```

The code is working like a charm for all of my forms but i am not sure if that aproach is not dangerous or vulnerable.

Comment: Your use of variable variables makes it a lot less readable; so I hope nobody but yourself ever has to maintain it, especially if they're a homicidal maniac who knows where you live

Comment: You're also failing to validate your column names in any way, so it's vulnerable to SQL injection if somebody manipulates one of your post keys

Comment: I hide the validation part, cause i think it will make the post too long, but thanks in advance i will try to make it more readable.

Comment: And i edit a little bit to become more readable

Comment: htmlentities and strip_tags are not suitable for escaping database input.